# bash file comparison line by line with selected string

Tags: bash

let us say i have two files a.txt, b.txt

```
a.txt

87621   3bde   NDF
87621   2dfg   NDF
87621   cdef   NDF
87621   abcd   NDF

b.txt

93291   abcd   NDF
93291   2dfg   NDF
93291   adbf   NDF
93291   gdrg   NDF
```

My script should create a file , by matching column 2 of both the files 
and create a file with matching string in new file c.txt like below

```
c.txt

2dfg
abcd
```

I tried several options, but not succeded, can you help !

Comment: Typically you show what you tried, and we can tell you where we find errors. I can think of an [awk](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/awk.1posix.html) and a [join](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/join.1.html) answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
comm -12 <(awk '{print $2}' a.txt | sort) <(awk '{print $2}' b.txt | sort) > c.txt
```

#### Explanation

- `<(...)` is a [process substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution). i.e. the output of the commands within the `(...)` is substituted and used as the two inputs to `comm`.
- `awk '{print $2}' a.txt` prints only the second field of each line.
- `sort` sorts the output ready for input into `comm`.
- `comm` compares two sorted files. The `-12` flags suppress the lines that are unique to each file, only printing the common lines (see `man comm` for more details).

Answer (score 1):

This reads all the lines in `a.txt` and keeps track of all of its column 2 values.  It then reads `b.txt` and prints out any repeated values of column 2:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {seen[$2]=1; next} seen[$2]==1 {seen[$2]++; print $2}' a.txt b.txt
abcd
2dfg
```

The `awk` command can be divided into the two parts.  The first part is:

```
NR==FNR {seen[$2]=1; next}
```

`awk` first tests whether the total number of records (lines) processed, `NR`, is the same as the number of records processed in this file, `FNR`.  This is true only for the first file processed which is `a.txt` in this case.  Thus, for every line in `a.txt`, the associative array `seen` with a key set to the value of the second column, `$2`, is set to a value of `1`.  This will be used to indicate that this value of column-2 was "seen" in `a.txt`.  The following command is `next` which tells `awk` to skip the rest of the commands and go get the next record.

The second part is:

```
seen[$2]==1 {seen[$2]++; print $2}
```

Because of the `next` command in the first part above, this part is only executed by file `b.txt`.  This part begins with a test: it checks to see if the column-2 value, `$2`, for this record has been seen before.  If is has been seen before once, then the commands in braces are executed.  The first command in braces, `seen[$2]++` increments the value of `seen` so that we will never process this value of column-2 again.  (Consequently, repeat values of column-2 are ignored.)  The second command simply prints the value of column-2 that had been seen before in `a.txt`.

If we can trust that there are no repeated values for column 2, a simpler script is possible:

```
$ awk '{print $2}' a.txt b.txt | sort | uniq -d
2dfg
abcd
```

Comment: This presumes that neither file contains duplicate lines.

Comment: @Sparhawk OK.  That is handled now too.

Comment: Nice! (Although my awk-fu is not good enough to understand the whole command.)

Answer (score 0):

The following perl one-liner will do the job:

```
perl -lane 'BEGIN{%h}$h{$ARGV."\n".$F[1]}++;END{foreach(keys(%h)){s/.*\n//;$f{$_}++};for(keys(%f)){print if$f{$_}>1}}' a.txt b.txt > c.txt
```